# using cloudsql proxy without credentials

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm currently trying to deploy phpmyadmin on GKE to use with google cloud SQL.
I'm following this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine.

But is there some way to connect to google cloud SQL without supplying credentials to cloudsql-proxy pod?

I'd like to have the phpmyadmin users to supply their own credentials using browser and not having to update the phpmyadmin deployment when they change - they are unnecessary to store in this case I think. PHPMyAdmin will not try to connect to SQL server on its own.

I've tried to add my GKE cluster to authorized networks of google cloud SQL, but I got an error saying, that internal networks are not allowed.

What should I do in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've re-read the docs and realized that db-credentials and instance-credentials are different thing. I created service account which is used by cloudsql-proxy to access the cloud SQL instance. DB credentials is not something that I should supply to cloudsql-proxy.